# Why do I have to display:block items so they align below each other in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox

The CSS code below was supposed to make every item of the form to be in a single column, like, one below the other, but it doesn't work unless I add the code:

```
input {
    display:block;
}
```

Why does this happen and how could I achieve that using only the `#flex` rule block?

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding:0
    }
    
    #flex {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        justify-items: center;
        height: 90vh;
    }
```

```html
<div id='flex'>
      <form id='something'>
                <input type='email' />
                <input type='password' />
                <button>Entrar</button>
            </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#flex` element has only one child: `#something`, so the flex settings hardly have an effect, they definitely don't affect the grandchildren `input` and `button`, but only the direct child (`#something`). Apply your settings to `#something` - this will have the effect you are asking for since it affects the direct children of `#something`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#something {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div id='flex'>
  <form id='something'>
    <input type='email' />
    <input type='password' />
    <button>Entrar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Johannes's answer, you can make the inputs and button flex-items of the #flex div by making the #something form `display:contents`

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0
}

#something {
    display:contents;
}
    
#flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div id='flex'>
  <form id='something'>
      <input type='email' />
      <input type='password' />
      <button>Entrar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```